# How to select all available indices in a dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe `df` of multiple variables, with a number of irregularly indexed entries.

Let's say like this:

```
        X  Y  
0    60.0  0   
1    63.0  10      
4    80.0  10             
5    46.0  1            
9    73.0  10

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now, say that I have a list of externally provided indices, `indices`, like:

```
indices = [0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11]
```

How can I select all entries of `df['X']` which are part of the indices? My desired output is

```
        X  
0    60.0          
4    80.0                          
9    73.0
```

If I merely try to call `df['X'][indices]`, Python rightfully complains:

```
KeyError: '[2, 6, 11] not in index'
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
print(df.loc[df.index.isin(indices), 'X'])
```

```
0    60.0
4    80.0
9    73.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the `df`'s indices as a new column, and filter those using `.isin()`:

```py
# convert original indexes to new column
df["original_index"] = df.index
    
# filter based on list values
indices = [0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11]
df[df["original_index"].isin(indices)]
```

Output:

```
    x   y   original_index
0   60  0   0
4   80  10  4
9   73  10  9
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `.reset_index()`, which will move the original indices to a new column, and re-index the index:

```py
# convert original indexes to new column and re-index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)


# filter based on list values
indices = [0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11]
df[df["index"].isin(indices)]
```

Output:

```
  index x   y
0   0   60  0
2   4   80  10
4   9   73  10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gave it a try but got a little lost on why I'd benefit from reindexing and playing with a new column. Cheers.